# How to get Posts with Content Query out of only one Blog-Category

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog

I'm completely new in SharePoint, but today I was able to get the titles of posts out of a blog into the main page of my site collection. That was easy.

But now I want more:

1. Is it possible to display a featured image and some parts of the post-content – as it is known for a blog-overview? I saw something of thumbnail URL, but it wasn’t working for me…
2. And I would like to add the same content query into subpages of the site collection (no problem), with filters for blog categories. Only posts out of specific categories shall be displayed. Also tried to filter by category ID or name, but also without any success.

Thank you for any solutions or hints in advance.

Comment: Did you get it? Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show featured image & content from blog post. With the CQWP, you can now control how that content is displayed. You can wrap HTML code and styles to format the display nearly however you wish.

**I got one reference link which works on MOSS 2007.**

[Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Custom Item Style](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/customitemstyle/)

Comment: Did you tried above solution? Is it helpful for you?